# Mandrill API to send email with recipients(cc), but It also send mail to recipients(cc) as 'TO' using Django==1.11.10

Tags: python, django, mailchimp, mandrill

Code:

```
def send_mandrill_subscribe_wac(link,user_email, from_user, from_email='examplecc@abc.com'):
   mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY)
   #template_name = "Invited-user-email-for-someone-without-an-account"
   template_name = "invited-user-email-for-someone-without-an-account"
   template_content = [{'content': 'example content', 'name': 'example name'}]
   message = {
       'from_email': 'examplecc@abc.com',
       'to': [
           {
               'email': user_email,
               'type': 'to'
           },
           {
               'email': from_email,
               'type': 'cc'
           },
           {
               'email': 'examplecc2@abc.com',
               'type': 'cc'
           }
       ],
       'global_merge_vars': [
           {'content': user_email},
           {'name': "redirect_link", 'content': link},
           {'name': 'from_user', 'content': from_user}
       ],
      
   }

   return mandrill_client.messages.send_template(template_name=template_name, template_content=template_content, message=message)
```

In official Documentation they mentioned preserve_recipients set to True to send recipients, But don't know where to add this parameter.

Need help please

Answer (score 1):

preserve_recipients is a property of message from what I see at https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/

```
message = {
       'from_email': 'examplecc@abc.com',
       'preserve_recipients': true,
```